# Can I visit London with a US visit visa during a 11 hours lay over at LHR?

Tags: usa, uk, customs-and-immigration, layovers, b1-b2-visas

I hold an Indian passport and I am flying to Seattle, US from Bangalore, India via LHR, London and the layover is 11 hours. Can I visit London with the US visit visa I have (this is accepted in many countries I heard)?

Do British Airways provide any help in this kind of situation either to visit or stay comfy at airport?

Comment: This is covered in the linked question. The answer is _maybe_ you can leave the airport. If you haven't already got a UK visa, then you must apply on arrival.

Comment: @MichaelHampton To be clear, I don't think those hoping to use the transit without visa scheme "apply on arrival" for a visa; they just apply for entry (entry without a visa, as the name of the program indicates).

Comment: @phoog Right. They do so _when they arrive_.

Comment: Why do they have to over complicate it? Not interested in tourism income I guess :D

Answer (score 0):

The US visa lets you transit airside in the UK but it doesn't let you leave the international part of the airport.

Comment: Actually, the uk's online visa checker says that people considering a visitor in transit visa may be able to benefit from the transit without visa scheme if they meet one of a set of conditions, including holding a US visa. This visitor in transit visa is for those who will clear passport control; it is distinct from the direct airside transit visa, for those who will not.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I visit London with the US visit visa I have (this is accepted in many countries I heard)?

You heard wrong. (Schengen transit visa is the only one where a US *resident* visa makes the Schengen transit unnecessary but I am unaware of any visitor visas which a US visitor visa can replace.)

> Do British Airways provide any help in this kind of situation either to visit

No airline I ever heard of will help with visas.

> or stay comfy at airport

Sure, there are [lounges](http://www.britishairways.com/en-ca/information/lounges) if you have no status and flying on economy then there are paid lounges provided by the airport, I believe you will be at Terminal 5, Aspire The Lounge is one I remember there might be more.

Comment: Emirates will help arrange visas (in advance, but still done through the airline) for people with layovers in Dubai. They do this, of course, since the airline is state-owned, and so bringing visitors in and getting them to the mall nicely benefits everyone. That obviously doesn't help the OP, but it's an airline that helps with visas somewhere in the world.

Comment: @ZachLipton thanks for the correction, that's very interesting.

Comment: People considering a visitor in transit visa may be able to benefit from transit without visa, according to the uk's visa checker site.

Comment: Another example is Philippines who lets you in if you have a valid US visa

Comment: Turkey let indians have an e-visa, if they hold US or some other visas.